# SQLModel - How to use only few fields from the base model

Tags: python, fastapi, sqlmodel

In the below example given here: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/create-db-and-table/

```
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel

class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = None
```

How can create the schema which uses only `name` and `age` and ignores the other variables/rows ?

Comment: You don't have to declare other properties/columns if you don't want them.

Answer (score 1):

Does making `secret_name` Optional solves your problem?

```
class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    secret_name: Optional[str]
    age: Optional[int] = None

hero = Hero(name="some name", age=99)
```

Should work fine and you don't have to pass `secret_name` param

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in another answer, using a non-optional value in the `SQLModel` definition implies that column cannot be `Nullable` (SQL for `None`).